# github upload projects in batch

Tags: git, github

I have many projects to be uploaded on github.

Currently I'm uploading 1 by 1.

**Current method**

1. Create a project on github
2. git init
3. git commit -m "first commit"
4. git remote add origin https://github.com/.../....git
5. git push -u origin master

***Is there any other way to upload my local projects on github (in batch)?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [GitHub API for Repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create) to script/automate the first step (the rest can be scripted as well).

For example, consider [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robwierzbowski/5430952)

```
 # Usage: gcreate userName repoName "Description if any"
 gcreate () { 
   curl -u $ 1 https://api.github.com/user/repos -d " { \" name \ " : \" $ 2 \ " , \" description \ " : \" $ 3 \ " } "
 }
```

This is where I miss the "[Create new project by pushing](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#push-to-create-a-new-project)" feature of GitLab...

Comment: thank you very much @Vonc. At least I have something to check now. Really appreciated.